# ExtJs4 - AutoComplete ComboBox not displaying Empty Text

Tags: javascript, extjs, autocomplete, combobox, extjs4

I have a combo-box with following configuration.

```
{
    fieldLabel:'Service',
    xtype:'combo',
    displayField: 'srvcDesc',
    store: storeServiceCodeVar,
    valueField:'srvcCD',
    id:'serviceCodeId',
    name:'serviceCodeName',
    queryMode: 'remote',
    queryDelay:100,
    typeAhead: true,
    minChars:0,
    hideTrigger:true,
    forceSelection:true,
    maxHeight:23,
    deferEmptyText:false,
    autoSelect:true,
    fieldStyle:'text-transform:uppercase',
    listConfig: {
        loadingText: 'Loading...',
        // Custom rendering template for each item
        getInnerTpl: function() {
            return '<table width="200px"><tr><td height="5"></td></tr><tr valign="top"><td>Code:{srvcCD}</td></tr><tr><td height="2"></td></tr><tr valign="top"><td>Description:{srvcDesc}</td></tr><tr><td height="5"></td></tr></table>';
        },
        emptyText:'No Values Found'
    }
}
```

The issue is that when there is no data returned from the server, then emptyText (which has value - No values found) gets displayed for may be a millisecond and goes off. I want it to stay there till the next query if fired. How is it possible. I have tried with deferEmptyText but no luck.

Could someone throw some light on this. I am using ExtJS 4 and behavior is same in IE9 and Mozilla.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also struggling with this; it appears the emptyText value is being added to the DOM as expected, but the height of the containing element is being set to zero when no records are returned from the server. Currently looking through the Ext JS 4 source now for some inspiration...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From stepping through the source, it doesn't seem like there is any reference to the `listConfig.emptyText` being used to determine whether or not to set the element's height to a number other than zero.

I've ended up overriding the `alignPicker()` function which Ext.form.field.ComboBox inherits from Ext.form.field.Picker, and adding a check for `listConfig.emptyText`.

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.field.ComboBox, {

    alignPicker: function() {
        var picker, height;

        if (this.isExpanded) {
            // Get the picker component.
            picker = this.getPicker();

            if (this.matchFieldWidth) {
                // Set the default height to null, since we don't 
                // automatically want to have the height changed.
                height = null;

                // If our store exists, but the count is zero
                // and we've got no emptyText defined...
                if (picker.store && 
                    picker.store.getCount() === 0 && 
                    Ext.isEmpty(this.listConfig.emptyText)) {
                    // ...we set the height to zero. 
                    height = 0;
                }

                // Set the size of the picker component.
                picker.setSize(this.bodyEl.getWidth(), height);
            }

            if (picker.isFloating()) {
                this.doAlign();
            }
        }
    }

});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey Daniel, thanks for sharing the hack. Its great. For me, the emptyText works perfectly fine when a combo-box is created independently, but when merged with the code of remaining application, it stops displaying. I am also trying to locate that which part is affecting emptyText's behavior. I shall share here if found anything useful. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Hi - I'm not sure I understand your problem. What do you mean by 'created independently'? What is your existing application? The emptyText issue with the combobox you describe above is a known bug in Ext JS 4 (see http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?147005-4.0.6-Combobox-listview-collapsed-when-an-empty-array-is-returned), and for the time being this hack should work around your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the post Daniel. By mentioning 'created independently' I meant that if I create a test page and include the extjs library and test for emptyText then it works fine for me. But when I include that in my application then it didn't work. This I found while investigating things further and realized that this could be due to something modified by us in our application. But looking at what you have provided, this whole situation looks like an imbroglio. Thanks for sharing the hack though.

Answer (score 0):

A word of warning here.  I'm on ExtJs 4-0-6 and it seems that there is now some code in `Ext.form.field.ComboBox` and it no longer just relies on inheriting the method from `Ext.field.form.Picker`.

So, instead the above code should now override the code directly in `Ext.field.form.Picker` rather than in the `ComboBox`.

But admittedly, hopefully Sencha will fix this themselves soon in 4.1.